# How to build lineage graph for a complex example

Tags: graph, rdd

For a simple example, just like this:

```
val rdd1 = sc.makeRDD(20 to 100)
  .filter(_ % 8 == 0).map(Math.sqrt(_)).map(e1 => (e1.toInt, e1)).cache()
rdd1.collect
```

Of course we can observe the lineage from spark UI. Also, We can easily get lineage graph using `rdd1.toDebugString`. But when I have a complex application (just like KMeansExample), we always see only a job at one time.

So how can I obtain the whole graph for all jobs? But how can I automatically get a lineage graph or some  structured format for representation lately?

Comment: add some more info...

Comment: Thanks for replying,I mean that, for one simple example just having a one job(Like the question above), we can use api toDebugString to get rdd dependencies, then we can get lineage. But when we have complex applicaiton (have many jobs), each job have each  sungraph  in SparkUI. How I can get whole lineage for all jobs to form only graph.( One graph demostate all RDD dependencies.)